# SpringBoot 1.5.7 - Does code-to-interface principle applies to @restcontroller classes and why?

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, proxy, aop

Hello Spring Community,

AFAIK, Code to interface principle make life easier to spring, so it will use JDK proxy and not CGLib proxy.

So this applies to RestController classes ? 
will spring need to create proxy classes for restController classes ? 
maybe only if i have some AOP in there ?

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: *maybe only if i have some AOP in there ?*-- this is a bit unclear. please clarify that.

Comment: Why do you think you need to make spring's life easier. It's the reverse. Spring should make your life easier. And it supports CGLib proxies for that reason. They work fine and allow avoiding useless interfaces (for controllers and other spring beans).

Comment: AOP, i mean if i have advices in my class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.